# how to fix this err in andriod simulator: Unable to load script.Make sure you are either running a Metro server

Tags: react-native

I created AwesomeProject and run `react-native run-android` in root directly of my project, message in android simulator is as follows:

Unable to load script.Make sure you are either running a Metro server or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.

To fix this err i try to run :
`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`
but it didn't work.[message in android simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr35g.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the bundler first, run

```
 npm start
```

or

```
 react-native start
```

in the root of your project.

Comment: but when run `npm start` or `react-native` start it give: 

 
`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE`
`npm ERR! errno 126`
`npm ERR! my_app@0.1.0 start:react-native-scripts start`
`npm ERR! Exit status 126`
`npm ERR! `
`npm ERR! Failed at the my_app@0.1.0 start script.`
`npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional` logging output above.